# How to make automaic changes in the Orientation?

Tags: iphone

I want to change the Orientation according to my application so how i can do this.Actually i am new in this field.

Answer (score 0):

Include the following in your UIViewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Edit: If you want to limit the orientations that are acceptable, instead of `return YES;` You can use `return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;` for example.